# How to calculate the scale factor for current window in WxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to calculate the scale factor for my current window in WxWidgets.Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [wxWindow::GetContentScaleFactor()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a6f230d4db56d1d2ab364fe1491f2e9ba) or something else? If so, you'd need to explain what...